# How to create zip archive contains files with certain extensions only

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I need to create zip archive which should contain files with certain extensions only, but I need to save the structure of the original directory.

For example, I have a directory with the following structure:

```
dir\
  sub_dir1\
    1.exe
  sub_dir_2\
    1.txt
    1.exe
  1.txt
  1.bat
```

and I need to get an archive with the following structure (only .exe and .bat files):

```
dir\
  sub_dir1\
    1.exe
  sub_dir_2\
    1.exe
  1.bat
```

I know how to find these files via Directory.GetFiles method:

```
var ext = new List<string> {".exe", ".bat"};
var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Where(s => ext.Any(e => s.EndsWith(e));
```

but I don't know how to save the archive's structure then.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: Do you want to know how to build a zip or how to find the files?

Comment: @Waescher Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the files with extension .exe and .bat from all the sub directories like:

```
IList<FileInfo> info = null;    
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

info = dirInfo
       .GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .Where( f => f.Extension
                    .Equals(".exe", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                 || f.Extension
                    .Equals(".bat", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        )
        .ToList()
        ;
```

Then based on this FileInfo list you can create you zip and folder structure.You can find the fileinfo details [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if you're going to do that, you should be using the [`EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `GetFiles()`: the former is lazy enumeration; the latter aggressive: it won't return until it's collected the entire result set. Further the original poster needs to traverse the entire subtree: you need to use `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, it should be  - SearchOption.AllDirectories. I edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\temp", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` will return an array with the full file paths like:

```
[C:\temp\dir1\app1.exe]
[C:\temp\dir2\subdir1\app2.exe]
[C:\temp\dir3\subdir2\subdir3\app3.exe]
```

So you won't have any trouble to put these files in a zip container with [ZipArchive.CreateEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346.aspx) because this method will create the same directory structure in the zip. However, you should remove the `C:\` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this very nice [tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/974/zip-archives-csharp-dotnet) will help you to do that.

If you want to keep empty folder in the target zip, maybe you have to use `ZipArchive.CreateEntry` method to do. In this demo, the author only use `ZipArchive. CreateEntryFromFile` method to archive a file from a file path.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [DotNetZip](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) library for solving your problem. For example the following code snippet can help you. Use `CreateZip()` method. In brief you should find files for writing to archive `GetFileNames()` and create zip file using `CreateZipFromFileNames()`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create zip archive from root directory with search patterns
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootDirectory">Root directory</param>
    /// <param name="searchPatterns">Search patterns</param>
    /// <param name="zipFileName">Zip archive file name</param>
    public static void CreateZip(string rootDirectory, List<string> searchPatterns, string zipFileName)
    {
        var fileNames = GetFileNames(rootDirectory, searchPatterns, true);
        CreateZipFromFileNames(rootDirectory, zipFileName, fileNames);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get file names filtered by search patterns
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootDirectory">Root diirectory</param>
    /// <param name="searchPatterns">Search patterns</param>
    /// <param name="includeSubdirectories">True if it is included files from subdirectories</param>
    /// <returns>List of file names</returns>
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFileNames(string rootDirectory, List<string> searchPatterns, bool includeSubdirectories)
    {
        var foundFiles = new List<string>();
        var directoriesToSearch = new Queue<string>();

        directoriesToSearch.Enqueue(rootDirectory);

        // Breadth-First Search
        while (directoriesToSearch.Count > 0)
        {
            var path = directoriesToSearch.Dequeue();

            foreach (var searchPattern in searchPatterns)
            {
                foundFiles.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
            }

            if (includeSubdirectories)
            {
                foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
                {
                    directoriesToSearch.Enqueue(subDirectory);
                }
            }
        }

        return foundFiles;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create zip archive from list of file names
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootDirectroy">Root directory (for saving required structure of directories)</param>
    /// <param name="zipFileName">File name of zip archive</param>
    /// <param name="fileNames">List of file names</param>
    private static void CreateZipFromFileNames(string rootDirectroy, string zipFileName, IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
    {
        var rootZipPath = Directory.GetParent(rootDirectroy).FullName;

        using (var zip = new ZipFile(zipFileName))
        {
            foreach (var filePath in fileNames)
            {
                var directoryPathInArchive = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)).Substring(rootZipPath.Length);
                zip.AddFile(filePath, directoryPathInArchive);
            }
            zip.Save();
        }
    }
```

Example of use:

```
CreateZip("dir", new List<string> { "*.exe", "*.bat" }, "myFiles.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Didgeridoo said: [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). But [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) lets you be even more expressive. For instance:

```
string cwd = Environment.CurrentDirectory ;
try
{
  Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"c:\root\of\directory\tree\to\be\zipped" ;
  using ( ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile() )
  {
    zipfile.AddSelectedFiles( "name = *.bat OR name = *.exe" , true ) ;
    zipfile.Save( @"c:\foo\bar\my-archive.zip") ;
  }
}
finally
{
  Environment.CurrentDirectory = cwd ;
}
```

---

**Edited To Note:** DotNetZip used to live at Codeplex. Codeplex has been shut down. The old archive is still [available at Codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It looks like the code has migrated to Github:

- https://github.com/DinoChiesa/DotNetZip. Looks to be the original author's repo.
- https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. This looks to be the currently maintained version. It's also packaged up an available via Nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

---

Comment: Thank you for note about `AddSelectedFiles()` method, but correct search criteria will be `"name = *.bat OR name = *.exe"`.

Comment: @Didgeridoo &mdash; you have a point. Clearly, my caffeine titration was a bit off this morning :)